# calculate significance

Tags: statistical-significance, post-hoc

Recently I observed that in a foreign language class many were left-handed (I think about 80% of 20 people).
Now I wonder if I can draw something out of that and at first place, I would like to calculate the significance.

But how do I proceed? Is it just a text book example and I can use a procedure given in each book?

Comment: An online site says that in the general population about 10% of people are left handed. Maybe you want to test whether foreign language students are different from the gen'l pop. in this regard. Then you might test null hypothesis $H_0: p = .10$ vs $H_a: p > .10$ in FL student group. With $X = 16$ in $n = 10$ left-handers, you could do a test and see of your estimate $\hat p = .8$ for LF students is 'significantly different' from 10%. If that's what you want, there's a formal test for that. Maybe clarify that in your Question.

Comment: yep, that's it! You even clarified my question I had in mind :) Thanks! I will check if I can calculate it.

Comment: If the true proportion of left-handers among FL students were 10%, then chances of getting 16 or more left-handers in a **randomly chosen** sample of 20 FL students would be very tiny:  3.263468e-13. So you could say that's a highly significant departure from what would be expected. // In R statistical software `sum(dbinom(16:20, 20, .1))` returns 3.263468e-13, using the binomial distribution. // Seeing 5 or more in 20 would be unusual, something like 4 chances in 100.

Comment: the sum is not necessary?! Ok, the probability is very small, how do I use this to check my hypothese? How do you know that 5 or more would be unusual?

Comment: ah, got it. For 4 people p=13% and for 5 people it is p<5%, so less than our alpha level. Is that correct?
I'm using the p-value for a while now but never calculated it on my own.. totally different story..

Comment: It is not possible to calculate a statistical significance for a *post hoc* hypothesis (that is, one generated from observing the data).  Any use of a textbook procedure is guaranteed to produce an optimistically strong sense of "significance" and therefore should be understood as being potentially misleading (at best), if not outright wrong.

Comment: This is interesting.. in reality, post hoc is the most important situation, or not? What would it change, if I calculated the significance before observing the data?

Comment: You can't compute significance without data--but you can formulate hypotheses before you examine the data.  That's essential.  It's great to use data to create hypotheses--*but you need independent data for testing those hypotheses.*

Comment: but my null hypothese won't be affected by that? In the example above I test whether 10 % of the people are left handed. And the alternative hypothese would be "more or less than 10 %" are left handed. If I do this before or after taking into account data wouldn't change anything?!

Comment: Sorry for not looking back here sooner: Intended to bring up @whuber's point after you'd thought about testing a bit. The point he makes is _crucial._ // I look out the window at cars passing by. Five of the first 6 cars I see all have out-of-state license plates. I might formulate a null hypothesis that traffic around here has a lot of visitors from out of state. I can do that, but I need to _test_ my hypothesis on fresh randomly selected data. // I just got a poker hand with a worthless mix of low cards. I shouldn't automatically say the dealer is unfair.

Comment: ... There are ${52 \choose 5}$ poker hands. Over 2.5 million. Chances of that particular miserable hand are tiny. But I had to get _some_ one of the possible hands. //  Life is full of weird coincidences. A very few may be meaningful. But the vast majority are one-time coincidences in which one should not look for patterns.